# needs-restarting hangs on RHEL7

Tags: linux, redhat, rhel7

On RHEL7, running the command (as sudo) `needs-restarting` hangs, as does `needs-restarting -s` while `needs-restarting -r` comes back within 2 seconds. By "hangs" I mean that it takes a really long time and eventually my SSH session times out. This was working fine until recently. What can I do to investigate the issue (barring "restart'll fix 'er")?

Relevant man page: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/needs-restarting.1.html

Note that I restarted the server and then `needs-restarting` completed in a couple of seconds. But this is clearly not ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`needs-restarting --reboothint` checks the install date of a handful of [packages that Red Hat has decided need a reboot to take effect](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/27943). kernel and libc, but also TLS libs and systemd. Compare against system boot time, easy.

`needs-restarting` without the reboot hint option is a much more intensive query. Search through smaps of every running process for file descriptors. Search rpmdb for owning package and check install time against process start time.   If `--services`, search the process for cgroups that look like a systemd service.  If you have a large amount of processes, open files, or memory, this will be slow. Or if rpmdb is on slow storage.

A simple solution is to reboot if any packages were updated. Proving that the system can go down and come back up after changes is useful.

Selectively restarting services would reduce reboots. But how are you finding these if `needs-restarting` bogs down?  And when was the last update cycle where you didn't have a kernel to install?

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. And explains why a reboot "fixes it". I think the answer, for our use case, is to include the `-r` flag call it good enough.

Comment: Oh, also, FWIW I rebooted this box yesterday because of this issue and it is already hanging on `needs-restarting -s` -- this box has not exhibited this problem in _years_ that it's been in use, until a week ago.

Comment: `--reboothint` is incomplete, it does not cover when, say, you only update `httpd` on a web server, without any `kernel` or `glibc` update.  Review what packages update, and schedule a restart of the service if it was upgraded.